# Spring Batch - Connection Refused in some Unit Tests

Tags: junit, database-connection, spring-batch

If I run all(31) the unit test together, I get following connection error in 2 - 3 unit tests, however if I run those tests individually, the run successfully. Can you please guide me on this strange behaviour. I am using Spring 3.0.6, Spring batch 2.1.7 and Oracle XE database.

below is the error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext   
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)   
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)   
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)   
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)   
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)   
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)   
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)   
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)   
    ... 40 more   
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:293)   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)   
    ... 47 more   
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:280)   
    ... 52 more   
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:536)   
              .............   
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:840)   
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)   
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)   
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)   
    ... 53 more   
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)   
    ..............   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)   
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)   
    ... 64 more   
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect   
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)   
                 ............................   
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)   
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)   
    ... 69 more
```

Comment: Does the tests run in parallel, or one after each other?

Comment: One after each other. I think this is how maven and eclipse run them one by one.

Comment: i am more interessted in: wherther or not all additonal threds startet in one test are finished before the next starts.

Comment: I am starting no thread in my unit test. These are very simple Test classes. I am using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and
@ContextConfiguration(context.xml) annotations on the top of each class.
Do you think loading context in every time be the problem?

Comment: And Spring Batch does not start a job?

Comment: It do start the job. All the tests run spring batch job and processes 50 - 100 records

Answer (score 1):

Something like this happened to me before. It was solved when I changed the IP of the database from 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.1.27 (the IP of my computer in my network, it can be found doing ip config in windows or ifconfig in linux). It might not be a permanent solution, but it dodges a bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue:
Root cause:
All available connections spent

Solution:
Closing the connection after use.